# Google Apps Script HTML Service function not running onclick

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have a form on a Google Apps Script HTML Service page.  When I click the Submit button nothing is happening.

The code on the button is

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" 
    onclick="google.script.run
                       .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
                       .updateText(this.parentNode)"/>
<button class="button cancel" onclick="google.script.host.close()">Cancel</button>
```

The code for the submit button is lifted from another project, where it runs happily.
The code for the cancel button is working fine.

Currently, nothing happens when I click the submit button (the window does not close and the `updateText()` function is not running.

`updateText()` runs fine if I call it manually in the script editor (it's just putting a value in a fixed field for the purposes of debugging).

```
function updateText(form){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet_id");
  ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(3,3).setValue("Test"); 
}
```

Comment: What script/code calls the html page? Show it.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? If so, which error are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

HTTML:

```
<form>
<!-- along with the rest of your form -->
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit" onclick="updateText(this.parentNode);"/>
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
</form>
<script>
  function updateTest(obj) {
  google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();})
.updateText(obj);
  }
  </script>
```

GS:

```
function updateText(form){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet_id");
  ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(3,3).setValue("Test"); 
  return;
}
```